# Obtener día del mes y mes con dos dígitos. Java

Tags: java

soy nuevo en java y necesito de una variable LocalDate obtenerla en formato String pero solo el día del mes y el mes. Ej:

`LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.of(2020, Month.SEPTEMBER, 1);`

Necesito obtener `0109`.
He intentado hacer lo siguiente:

```
System.out.println("Código ->" + fecha.getDayOfMonth()
             + "" + fecha.getMonthValue());
```

Pero me da `19`, supongo que habrá que utilizar algún `format`,gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una forma de hacerlo es utilizando **`DateTimeFormatter`** con el patron **`ddMM`**, donde `dd` son los días y `MM` es el mes en número.

Te dejo un ejemplo:

```
DateTimeFormatter formato = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMM");

LocalDate fecha = LocalDate.of(2020, 9, 1);

System.out.println("Código ->" + fecha.format(formato));
```

He de recalcar que tú `Month.SEPTEMBER` es igual al 9 que coloque, valga la redundancia.

Para utiliza **`DateTimeFormatter`** debes importar **`java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter`**

> [DateTimeFormatter](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html): Formateador para imprimir y analizar objetos
>   de fecha y hora.

Comment: Buenas, gracias. He decidido usar lo siguiente a partir de tu respuesta:  
String fechaFormateada = fecha.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("ddMM"));
  System.out.println( "Código ->" fechaFormateada);     Gracias

Comment: Me alegro que te funcionara de guia, solo recalcar que si vas a utilizar varias veces el formateo es mejor dejar `DateTimeFormatter` de forma declarada a estarla instanciado o creando cada vez que apliques el format. Espero darme a entender.

Comment: Vale, solo me hacía falta para utilizarla en una función deriva de una clase.

Answer (score 2):

```
SimpleDateFormat formato = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM");
```

Puedes utilizar esto para dar un formato a las fechas. Donde **formato** es el nombre que tu quieras darle. Y dentro de los paréntesis puedes cambiar la estructura del formato.

Para utilizar el formato, puedes hacerlo de la siguiente manera:

```
formato.format(fecha.getTime());
```

Comment: Para tu ejercicio le he dado el formato que quieres, de día y mes. Un saludo!

Comment: Buenas, no sé si me he explicado. No quiero cambiar el formato de la fecha, solo quiero obtener de una fecha "x" el día y el mes en formato int o string pero donde cada numero esté formado por dos dígitos.

Comment: Para ello puedes utilizar un método getter por ejemplo, que te devuelva lo que quieras de la fecha, de este modo: `fecha.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);`

Comment: Con la clase **Calendar** puedes obtener lo que quieras de las fechas. Te invito a que la mires en la API o busques información sobre ella, te sera muy útil.

Comment: gracias, es la mejor explicación de toda la web (Y)